# Python Simple Salesforce - Upsert to CampaignMembers Object

Tags: upsert, python, campaign-member, simple-salesforce

I am trying to find an automated way to add contacts & leads to existing campaigns by using simple salesforce to upsert records to the CampaignMembers object. I have a CSV file with CampaignId and ContactId. However, I am getting an error that says `"salesforce_bulk.sal

Comment: Did you check Field Level Security?

Comment: Yes. @AdrianLarson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are `Marketing User`.

You can find `Marketing User` checkbox on the [User](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.user_fields.htm&type=5) record that you are using to load data. Campaign objects security depends on this permission.

> When enabled and the user has Read permission on contacts or the Import permission on Leads, and Edit permission on campaigns, the user can create, edit, and delete campaigns, configure advanced campaign setup, and add campaign members and update their statuses with the Data Import Wizard.

**Update**

Double verify all the permissions listed [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.faq_import_campaign_who_can_import.htm&type=5) are taken care of.

After an examination, the problem seems to be in the library [salesforce-bulk](https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-bulk). The library has not been updated in a while and seems like it causes this issue due to invalid headers sent as discussed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255712/bulk-api-v2-get-job-status-failing-invalidbatch-field-name-not-found).

You can avoid it and use [simple-salesforce](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/)

Comment: I have system admin access and here are my field-security settings for Campaign Member object (see new image above). It seems correct to me. @MohithShrivastava

Comment: FLS is not the same thing as Marketing User. You need to check that setting on your User record.

Comment: Marketing User was already enabled for my User record. @DavidReed

Comment: @ParthPatel Can you add the campaign member records manually via the UI? Also make sure you are using your org username for running the job! I was able to replicate and moment I use marketing user checkbox the issue was fixed! So double check

Comment: Yes, I can add via the UI just not via API and everything is under my username already. Thanks. @MohithShrivastava

Comment: I also updated the answer! I realized there is one more FLS setting I had to enable!

Comment: Still no luck. Does the primary campaign source field affect what I am trying to do with the 'CampaignMember' object? @MohithShrivastava

Comment: It should not! But the help article pointed to a related issue! Looks like this might have to do with the python lib because all goes fine from postman or dataloder! Can you point me to the library?

Comment: I am using simple salesforce. I posted my code above @MohithShrivastava

Comment: Can you try using postman and see if you get the same error when you hit the endpoint the lib does? This way we narrow down the root cause to lib?

Comment: Postman is out of my wheelhouse. I don't come from a traditional programming background. I have an intermediate understanding of Python but that's the only programming language I know. Is there an alternative? @MohithShrivastava

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126271/discussion-between-parth-patel-and-mohith-shrivastava).